# C#.net, raising events while processing a long task, show a form which can have "Pause" and "Continue" to continue processing

Tags: c#, winforms, batch-processing

I process a file line by line reading various events that have a time stamp and data associated with them. I want to be able to show a form while doing processing which I need to interact with and intercept some events by having a button saying interrupt EventX and if it is pressed it will show the event data in a rich text box field when this event is reached sometime in the future. I can then change some of that event data (let's say I simulate some conditions) and when I press "Resume" it should resume processing by raising an event to the intended subscriber for further processing.

So I need an interceptor that will be pass-trough mechanism when a certain form element is pressed and pass that data to the intended subscriber. 
I am ok to wait synchronously for modifying data and pressing "Resume"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a Responsive GUI while doing a long running operation, you need some form of Multitasking. Wich means either async/await or any of the many Multithreading (Thread and BackgroundWorker, mostly) approaches

While pause and resume could be added, doing so usually more work then it is worth. At the very least you run into issues like still held filehandles or race conditions. Often a "cancel" action is way enough/better then a full stop/resume mechanic.

As a Beginner I would advice you to use the BackgroundWorker. It is about as easy as getting into Multitasking via Multithreading can be. I even wrote a example for it a few years back:

```
#region Primenumbers
private void btnPrimStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        //Prepare ProgressBar and Textbox
        int temp = (int)nudPrim.Value;
        pgbPrim.Maximum = temp;
        tbPrim.Text = "";

        //Start processing
        bgwPrim.RunWorkerAsync(temp);
    }
}

private void btnPrimCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bgwPrim.IsBusy)
    {
        bgwPrim.CancelAsync();
    }
}

private void bgwPrim_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int highestToCheck = (int)e.Argument;
    //Get a reference to the BackgroundWorker running this code
    //for Progress Updates and Cancelation checking
    BackgroundWorker thisWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

    //Create the list that stores the results and is returned by DoWork
    List<int> Primes = new List<int>();


    //Check all uneven numbers between 1 and whatever the user choose as upper limit
    for(int PrimeCandidate=1; PrimeCandidate < highestToCheck; PrimeCandidate+=2)
    {
        //Report progress
        thisWorker.ReportProgress(PrimeCandidate);
        bool isNoPrime = false;

        //Check if the Cancelation was requested during the last loop
        if (thisWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Tell the Backgroundworker you are canceling and exit the for-loop
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        }

        //Determin if this is a Prime Number
        for (int j = 3; j < PrimeCandidate && !isNoPrime; j += 2)
        {
            if (PrimeCandidate % j == 0)
                isNoPrime = true;
        }

        if (!isNoPrime)
            Primes.Add(PrimeCandidate);
    }

    //Tell the progress bar you are finished
    thisWorker.ReportProgress(highestToCheck);

    //Save Return Value
    e.Result = Primes.ToArray();
}

private void bgwPrim_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void bgwPrim_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    pgbPrim.Value = pgbPrim.Maximum;
    this.Refresh();

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
    {
        //Show the Result
        int[] Primes = (int[])e.Result;

        StringBuilder sbOutput = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (int Prim in Primes)
        {
            sbOutput.Append(Prim.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        tbPrim.Text = sbOutput.ToString();
    }
    else 
    {
        tbPrim.Text = "Operation canceled by user or Exception";
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Tx Chris.I know BackgroundWorker. I need to be able to display a form, start processing and when I decide I would press a "Pause Event1" button which should update event flags: bool event1Intercept = true and when event1 is raised some time in the future, the processing stops (waits) and event data is displayed in txtBox.text property and "Continue Event1" button is enabled. When I change event1 data in txtBox and press "Continue Event1", the processing will continue with modified event being raised for final event handler to process. If event1Intercept=false processing continues uninterrupted

Comment: So my interaction with a form is not as simple as pressing Cancel.

Comment: Again, I would not try to add a Pause/Resume function. BGW is not really designed of it. You should be using Threads. And propably even **then**, this tends to be a lot more work then it is worth in the end. It would be not that hard to implement: All you need is a shared bool that the thread checks every itteration and then just Sleeps (rather then do processing) if it has the right value. As for Creating a GUI: You have to do it the other way around. Have the GUI ceate the BackgroundWorker. The Form.Shown() event is ideal to start stuff like a BGW.

Comment: So for the pause/unpause: All I really would need would be a boolean value "Pause" with default value false. The entire current content of DoWork is wrapped into the else part of a if statement. `if(paused) Thread.Sleep(1); Else //do what you do now`. I guess you would not even have to bother with Synchronisation in this case, unless you run into odd behavior. Imutable types like most ValueTypes and String can be freely exhanged. Only with Mutable type - in particular reference types - do you have to take precautions.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I will have multiple bool variables for pausing (for multiple event types). Pseudo code, especially for pausing code. Why Thread.Sleep(1)? Imagine I have a form private fields bool event1 = false, event2 = false which I can change using corresponding checkboxes. So when event1 becomes true (cbevent1.checked = true when user interacts with the form), when this event1 is created and raised a form method handles that and enters pause, updating txtevent1.text = event.data and waits for "btnContinue" to be pressed so the user can update txtevent1.text

Comment: Thread.Sleep() is so the idling BGW will not tax out a core. If you want to do an action on the "first cycle after the pause", you need additional bool variables for each function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Christofer,

I accepted you answer as you gave me some suggestions how to solve my problem.
You can see bellow how I solved this problem

Rad

```js
//class variable
private SimulatorRunner simulatorRunner;

//Code behind DevicesSimulatorForm form
private void RunSimulator()
{
 btnRerun.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood;
 ParameterizedThreadStart start = new ParameterizedThreadStart(RunSimulator);
 Thread simulatorProcessingThread = new Thread(start);
 simulatorProcessingThread.Start(this);
}

//This will run in a separate thread so when accessing controls Invoke is being used.
public void RunSimulator(object form)
{
 DevicesSimulatorForm devicesSimulatorForm = (DevicesSimulatorForm) form;
 simulatorRunner.Run(devicesSimulatorForm);
        devicesSimulatorForm.InvokeEx(formInner =>
 {
  formInner.btnRerun.BackColor = Color.LightGray;
  InitializeFields();
  InitializeTextBackBorder();
  InitializeButtonControls();
  running = false;
 });

}


public class SimulatorRunner
{
   public void Run(DevicesSimulator form)
    { 
    
      string buffer = "Some content read from file in a loop that needs to be passed 
                      to a rich text box when a boolean Intercept check box is true
                      and FormStatusIntercept will return true and with Thread.Sleep(1)
                      we will have a chance to update the buffer to the new value and by
                      unchecking Intercept check box we will exit while loop and continue
                      processing"      
      while (true)
      {
        if (FormStatusIntercept(form, ref buffer))
        {
          Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
        else
        {
          publishEventArgs.Buffer = buffer;
          break;
        }
      }

      PublishEvent?.Invoke(this, publishEventArgs);
   }
}

private bool FormStatusIntercept(DevicesSimulator simulatorForm, ref string buffer)
{
 string modifiedBuffer = buffer;
  //When btnFormStatus button is pressed it changes FormStatusContinued = true
  //which allows continuation of the processing by exiting while loop
 if (simulatorForm.FormStatusContinued == true)
 {
  simulatorForm.InvokeEx(form =>
  {
   if (form.rtbFormStatus.Text != modifiedBuffer)
   {
    modifiedBuffer = form.rtbFormStatus.Text;
   }
   form.FormStatusContinued = false;
   form.FormStatusInterceptPending = false;
  });
  buffer = modifiedBuffer;
  return false;
 }
 else if (simulatorForm.FormStatusIntercept == true)
 {
  if (simulatorForm.FormStatusInterceptPending == false)
  {
      //Whith check box pressed (true) we request a stop
      //and we enter a while loop with Thread.Sleep(1)
   simulatorForm.InvokeEx(form =>
   {
    form.btnFormStatus.Text = "Continue";
    form.rtbFormStatus.Text = modifiedBuffer;
    form.FormStatusInterceptPending = true;
   });
  }
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```